How to turn off a MOSFET in a case it fails and stays "ON"
how to turn a N-MOSFET (Q1) off, in case if fails and due to this error it remains in an "ON" state?
My idea is to add a second P-MOSFET to have redundancy. I don`t want to use a relay.
Vcc = 12V, uC voltage is 3V3


Prevention is surely better than cure and that means designing the circuit and choosing the MOSFET correctly. Maybe you have a very strangle application that requires this and, if so, you should state that.

What failure are you talking about here?  The microcontroller not de-asserting the output?  Or the MOSFET failing into a source-drain short?

How do you know it has failed? You will probably need some sensing on the load to be able to detect a fault.

I wonder why the need for the "redundancy cut-off" circuit. I am assuming that if the micro-controller failed the uC_1 pin will float (or grounded) and hence the NMOS gate will be pulled down to GND by R24 resistor (and uC_1 is grounded).

How about SCR crowbar blowing fuse?

Your solution is ideal. Well done!
Indeed, that is exactly the solution used in automotive-grade Battery Management Systems to drive the contactors. It avoids a single-point failure in case the lower MOSFET fails shorted or a wire to the load is accidentally grounded to the metal chassis.
(Placing two MOSFETs in series on the negative side is not as good a solution because it doesn't take care of the case of a wire to the load that is accidentally grounded to the metal chassis.)
If the load is inductive, I suggest you add a diode to absorb the inductive kickback (if you haven't already).

What you show can work, if your system needs to also disconnect the supply.
If the scope of your intent here is to only cut off the single load drive in the event of that FET failing, then two n-FETs in series would do this, perhaps cheaper and more reliably than what you propose (simulate it here):

As to why the FET might fail, this appnote gives some insight from an automotive point of view: https://www.vishay.com/docs/69294/an910.pdf
Their diagram shows disconnects for both the supply and each individual load. For your application you may want to consider a dedicated high-side switch that kills the entire power domain instead of a p-FET that just kills your one load.

OP's circuit is better because it also handles a fault of a short circuit at the negative end of the load (e.g. a pinched wire). Yours does not handle that situation.

In a typical auto application, the load (+) side would ordinarily go to a fuse (which itself could be an active element, e.g., a high-side load switch with protection.) OP's proposal would imply that the load's power needs to be routed through the controller to pick up that p-FET, then back out. That's two more points of failure compared to the one low-side wire.

The only issue I see  with this is if something shorts out one MOSFET, it's going to short out both and the situation is exactly the same as one MOSFET. If only one MOSFET shorts out, great, you saved the day. But you still end up back in the stating situation with no indication that one MOSFET failed shorted.

This also will have issues with higher supply voltages. If the bottom FET is off, the gate-source maximum voltage voltage of the top FET might be violated.

OP is switching 12V. Vgs isn't such an issue.

@hacktastical "hat's two more points of failure". Yes, but they are failsafe failures. A short to chassis on the low side driver is not failsafe. That ls why the automotive industry uses OP's circuit, not your circuit.
